# Shared library with a .COM file

Tags: c, dos, retro-computing

I think I want dynamic libraries for my .COM files.

I've been playing around with DOSMC lately to produce some tiny MS-DOS .COM files:

https://github.com/pts/dosmc

It can also produce static library (.LIB) files and also talks about how it's an optimising linker, compiling in functions but skipping those that aren't called. This is great for reducing individual file sizes, but over multiple programs, those few hundred bytes for `puts()` stack up.

Thinking back to my MS-DOS (and therefore QuickBASIC days), I remember executables QuickBASIC produced could either have the runtime compiled in or reference it via BRUN45.EXE. I was wondering if something similar is possible with a bare bones .COM file, or what I'd need to do to achieve that sort of system. Something like:

```
small1.com   300 bytes
small2.com   400 bytes
biglib.com   10000 bytes
```

With `small1.com` having a stub to run `biglib.com`, but with its own code at the end.

I guess this is dynamic linking, but it doesn't feel dynamic because it's not across different segments, and the linker could rely on everything in the library being at a particular address. It's also just one runtime library versus a whole bunch of DLLs.

Comment: MS-DOS does have just the tiniest bit of support for things like this. DOS function 4Bh has a "load overlay" sub-function you can use to load a .com (or .exe) file at a specified location in memory. Essentially everything beyond that is up to you though. There were various overlay linkers (e.g., Plink 86+, .RTLink+, Borland VROOM), but I don't believe any of them dealt with .COM files (and I'm not sure if they supported a shared library in .exe format either--they mostly deal with overlaying sections of a single executable to allow more code to occupy less memory).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Not sure any of those worked with .com files. IIRC (of course, it's been decades), .com files were limited to 64K total memory. Anything that used any more than that had to be in .exe format.

Comment: @KenWhite: DOS function 4B can (e.g., you can tell it to not do relocations when loading the file). We seem to be in agreement about the linkers though--as I said: "I don't believe any of them dealt with .COM files".

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Guess my *IIRC* failed, then. :-) It has been several decades - admittedly very rusty.

Comment: @KenWhite: With the proviso that I'm going from ancient memories too...